# Is there a way to find out how the table metrics in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

...is changing over time. I know time travel does not work on Information schema. So, wanted to know if there is an alternate approach

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by table metrics? Do you mean row counts, table size, number of micro partitions, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the alternative approach is to schedule a task with an insert query based on your query against information schema, that inserts the data into some table with a timestamp.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tasks-intro.html